# Download outlook emails from specific Folders

Tags: c#, outlook

I have written code for outllok addon such that when ever email arrives in inbox it should download , but the curret code is such that if it arrives into specific folder also it not getting get downloaded. Can some one guide me on this?

```
 private void ThisApplication_NewMail()
        {
            const string destinationDirectory = @"C:\TestFileSave";

            if (!Directory.Exists(destinationDirectory))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationDirectory);
            }

            MAPIFolder sentMail = Application.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail);

            Items sentMailItems = sentMail.Items;
            try
            {
                foreach (object collectionItem in sentMailItems)
                {
                    MailItem newEmail = collectionItem as MailItem;

                    if (newEmail == null) continue;

                    if (newEmail.Attachments.Count > 0)
                    {
                        for (int i = 1; i <= newEmail.Attachments.Count; i++)
                        {
                            if (newEmail.Attachments[i].FileName.Contains("Logic"))
                            {
                                string filePath = Path.Combine(destinationDirectory, newEmail.Attachments[i].FileName);
                                newEmail.Attachments[i].SaveAsFile(filePath);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
```

Comment: `when ever email arrives in inbox it should download`  That's not what this code does.

Comment: This code is downloading whenever I get a  email in outllok

Comment: It looks at the sent mail and determines if there are attachments and downloads the attachments.  Are we looking at the same code?

Comment: Also, the line Application.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder will blow up if there is no Explorer open (you can have an inspector only or neither explorer nor inspector). Change that line to Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder.

Comment: can u please suggest me how to do itt?

Comment: So here default folder is Inbox i dont want inbox even if mail arrives in other folsders it should download

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the [NewMailEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863686(v=office.15).aspx) event to get notified when a new mail arrives. Then you can get an instace of the just arrived item using the EntryID value passed to the NewMailEx event handler. The [GetItemFromID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869893.aspx) method of the Namespace class returns a Microsoft Outlook item identified by the specified entry ID (if valid).

Also you may consider handling the [ItemAdd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869609(v=office.15).aspx) event of the Items class. It is fired when one or more items are added to the specified collection. Be aware, this event does not run when a large number of items are added to the folder at once.

You can read more about that in the series of articles:

- [Outlook NewMail event unleashed: the challenge (NewMail, NewMailEx, ItemAdd)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/10/03/outlook-newmail-event/)
- [Outlook NewMail event: solution options](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/10/24/outlook-newmail-solution-options/)
- [Outlook NewMail event and Extended MAPI: C# example](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/01/outlook-newmail-extended-mapi/)
- [Outlook NewMail unleashed: writing a working solution (C# example)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/10/outlook-newmail-custom-solution/)

The [MarkForDownload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866920(v=office.15).aspx) property of Outlook items returns an OlRemoteStatus constant that determines the status of an item once it is received by a remote user. For example, the following example searches through the user's Inbox for items that have not yet been fully downloaded. If any items are found that are not fully downloaded, a message is displayed and the item is marked for download.

```
Sub DownloadItems()  
 Dim mpfInbox As Outlook.Folder  
 Dim obj As Object  
 Dim i As Integer 
 Set mpfInbox = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)  
 'Loop all items in the Inbox folder  
 For i = 1 To mpfInbox.Items.Count  
 Set obj = mpfInbox.Items.Item(i)  
 'Verify if the state of the item is olHeaderOnly  
 If obj.DownloadState = olHeaderOnly Then  
    MsgBox ("This item has not been fully downloaded.")  
 'Mark the item to be downloaded.  
    obj.MarkForDownload = olMarkedForDownload  
 End If  
 Next  
End Sub
```

Finally, you can use the [Start](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863925(v=office.15).aspx) method of the SyncObject class to begin synchronizing a user's folders using the specified Send\Receive group.

```
Public Sub Sync() 
 Dim nsp As Outlook.NameSpace  
 Dim sycs As Outlook.SyncObjects 
 Dim syc As Outlook.SyncObject 
 Dim i As Integer 
 Dim strPrompt As Integer 
 Set nsp = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
 Set sycs = nsp.SyncObjects 
 For i = 1 To sycs.Count 
   Set syc = sycs.Item(i) 
   strPrompt = MsgBox( _ 
   "Do you wish to synchronize " & syc.Name &"?", vbYesNo) 
   If strPrompt = vbYes Then 
     syc.Start 
   End If 
 Next 
End Sub
```